# Show that $\sinh(z^{2})$ is entire using the Cauchy Riemann equations

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-derivative, entire-functions

I was wondering if anyone could assist me with the above problem, I'm struggling to get the function in the form $u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ to then calculate the partial derivatives.

I understand that I need to use the chain rule, but would I first replace $z$ with $z=re^{i\theta}$ $\implies z^{2}=r^{2}e^{2i\theta}$. Then we would have that $f(z)=\sinh(r^{2}e^{2i\theta})$. I'm stuck here, any help would be great.

Comment: Maybe: Write $z^2$  in real and imaginary parts (each a function of $x$ and $y$), then use the addition formula for $\sin$ on that?

Comment: Try to use $z=a+bi$ and work with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall the identity $$\sinh z = \frac{e^z - e^{-z}}{2}.$$  Then $$\sinh z^2 = \frac{e^{x^2 - y^2} e^{2xy i} - e^{-(x^2-y^2)} e^{-2xy i}}{2}.$$  Then isolate the real and imaginary components from $$\frac{e^{x^2 - y^2}}{2} (\cos 2xy + i \sin 2xy) - \frac{e^{-(x^2-y^2)}}{2} (\cos (-2xy) + i \sin (-2xy)).$$  The rest is straightforward.

Comment: Brilliant this makes sense, for some reason my mind was going blank when getting the second line.

Comment: and note isn't it $sinh(z)=\frac{1}{2}(e^{z}-e^{-z})$ i think your $+$ should be a $-$?

Comment: @Gibberish Indeed, I wrote the formula for $\cosh$ instead of $\sinh$.  I have had too much caffeine and not enough sleep today

Comment: after getting it in to the form $u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ would i just take the partial derivatives of $u$ and $v$ with respect to $x$ and $y$? and to do this i'm assuming i will need to use the product rule+chain rule?

Comment: Correct, you'd compute the partial derivatives and use Cauchy-Riemann.  Shouldn't be too difficult; if you're still encountering trouble, let us know.

Answer (score 0):

Consider
\begin{align}
\sinh(it)&=\frac{e^{it}-e^{-it}}{2}=i\frac{e^{it}-e^{-it}}{2i}=i\sin t \\
\cosh(it)&=\frac{e^{it}+e^{-it}}{2}=\cos t
\end{align}
Then, if $z=x+iy$, $z^2=(x^2-y^2)+2ixy$ and
\begin{align}
\sinh(z^2)
&=\sinh(x^2-y^2)\cosh(2ixy)+\cosh(x^2-y^2)\sinh(2ixy)\\
&=\sinh(x^2-y^2)\cos(2xy)+i\cosh(x^2-y^2)\sin(2xy)\\
\end{align}
Thus you have
\begin{align}
u(x,y)&=\sinh(x^2-y^2)\cos(2xy)\\
v(x,y)&=\cosh(x^2-y^2)\sin(2xy)
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks,I think you mean $cosh(2ixy) =cos(2xy)$ in $u(x,y)$ and the line above?

Comment: @Gibberish Yes, sorry, I forgot to remove h after copy-pasting